# How to write text in multiline(in a paragraph)?

Tags: php, imagettftext

When i use this code,I can make a image out of text,but in a single line,

```
function writetext($image_path,$imgdestpath,$x,$y,$angle,$text,$font,$fontsize) {
      $image=imagecreatefromjpeg("$image_path");
      $height = imageSY($image);
      $width = imageSX($image);
      $color = imagecolorallocate($image,0,0,0);
      $textwidth = $width;
      imageTTFtext($image,$fontsize,$angle,$x,$y,$color,$font, $text );
      ImageJPEG($image,$imgdestpath);
}
```

Please tell how to make this image in a multiline paragraph??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For each line you need new imageTTFtext function to be called with new value for $y
for example:

```
$text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer non nunc lectus.     Curabitur hendrerit bibendum enim dignissim tempus. Suspendisse non ipsum auctor metus consectetur eleifend. Fusce cursus ullamcorper sem nec ultricies. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vivamus massa justo, pharetra et sodales quis, rhoncus in ligula. Integer dolor velit, ultrices in iaculis nec, viverra ut nunc.';

// Break it up into pieces 125 characters long
$lines = explode('|', wordwrap($text, 115, '|'));

// Starting Y position
$y = 513;

// Loop through the lines and place them on the image
foreach ($lines as $line)
{
imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, 50, $y, $font_color, $font, $line);

// Increment Y so the next line is below the previous line
$y += 23;
}
```

[source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php)

Comment: what in the case,if I take a input of a paragraph(with breaks) ie $text="Hello, How are you??<br>
What do you need??<br>
hello world";

How to write this same on image?

Answer (score 0):

```
function writeonimage(){ 

// Create Image From Existing File
$jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('wp-content/themes/ibestquotes/images/background.jpg');

// Allocate A Color For The Text
$white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 255, 255, 255);

// Set Path to Font File
$font_path = 'wp-content/themes/ibestquotes/fonts/arial-italic.ttf';

// Set Text to Be Printed On Image
$text = get_the_title($_REQUEST['did']);

// Break it up into pieces 25 characters long
$lines = explode('|', wordwrap($text, 25, '|'));

// Starting Y position
$y = 100;

// Loop through the lines and place them on the image
foreach ($lines as $line)
{
imagettftext($jpg_image, 20, 0, 40, $y, $white, $font_path, $line);

// Increment Y so the next line is below the previous line
$y += 40;
}

// Send Image to Browser but we are using download image
//imagejpeg($jpg_image,'wp-content/themes/ibestquotes/name.jpg');


header("Content-type: image/jpeg");  
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache");  
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="avatar.jpg"');
imagejpeg($jpg_image);

// Clear Memory
imagedestroy($jpg_image); 
}


//This code is working on 
http://ibestquotes.com/?t=d&did=56
```